# Referencing another variable in a global variable in swift

Tags: swift

I don't understand why the following doesn't work in Swift:

```
class SomeClass {
    var foo = 1
    var bar = self.foo + 1
}
```

and what's the way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you cannot use `self` in that scope to define default values for properties. I believe it is due to the fact that you cannot use `self` before the object is properly initialized. You could use an explicit initializer instead.

```
class SomeClass {
    var foo: Int
    var bar: Int

    init() {
        self.foo = 1
        self.bar = self.foo + 1
    }
}
```

You can, however, access static members.

```
class SomeClass {
    static let initialValue = 1
    var foo = initialValue
    var bar = initialValue + 1
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks for the explanation! Strange, but I get it.